# quickbooks online recievepaymentadd

Tags: integration, quickbooks-online

i am trying to add a payment to quickbooks online from my web app.  This is the xml that i am sending:

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <?qbxml version="6.0"?>
          <QBXML>
                <SignonMsgsRq>
                      <SignonTicketRq>
                            <ClientDateTime>2013-05-09T01:37:58</ClientDateTime>
                            <SessionTicket>V1-115-Q04ffswegvh9uzxaw8qrud:689712285</SessionTicket>
                            <Language>English</Language>
                            <AppID>688664435</AppID>
                            <AppVer>1</AppVer>
                      </SignonTicketRq>
                </SignonMsgsRq>
                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                      <ReceivePaymentAddRq>
                            <ReceivePaymentAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE"> <!-- required -->
                                  <CustomerRef> <!-- required -->
                                        <ListID >5</ListID> <!-- optional -->
                                  </CustomerRef>
                                  <ARAccountRef> 
                                        <FullName>Accounts Receivable:Customer Receivables</FullName>
                                  </ARAccountRef>
                                  <AppliedToTxnAdd> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
                                        <TxnID useMacro="MACROTYPE" >143</TxnID> <!-- required -->
                                  </AppliedToTxnAdd>
                                  <TxnDate >2013-05-09</TxnDate>
                                  <RefNumber >123</RefNumber>
                            </ReceivePaymentAdd>
                      </ReceivePaymentAddRq> 
                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
          </QBXML>
```

I get an error saying:

```
 SAX parser encountered an error parsing request file.
Exception from other package:
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "ReceivePaymentAdd" must match "(CustomerRef,ARAccountRef?,TxnDate?,RefNumber?,TotalAmount?,PaymentMethodRef?,Memo?,DepositToAccountRef?,CreditCardTxnInfo?,(IsAutoApply|AppliedToTxnAdd+)
```

I just need to apply a payment to an invoice.  The payment will always be for the full amount of the invoice.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks Randy

Comment: This is a perfectly valid programming API question, I don't know why people are down-voting you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of tags in qbXML *matters*.

So if the Intuit OSR reference shows you that the correct order of tags is:

```
<CustomerRef>
  <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
</CustomerRef>
<ARAccountRef>
  <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
</ARAccountRef>
<TxnDate>DATETYPE</TxnDate>
<RefNumber>STRTYPE</RefNumber>
...
<AppliedToTxnAdd> ...
```

And you instead send tags in this order:

```
<CustomerRef>
  <ListID >5</ListID>
</CustomerRef>
<ARAccountRef> 
  <FullName>Accounts Receivable:Customer Receivables</FullName>
</ARAccountRef>
<AppliedToTxnAdd>
  <TxnID useMacro="MACROTYPE" >143</TxnID>
</AppliedToTxnAdd>
<TxnDate >2013-05-09</TxnDate>
<RefNumber >123</RefNumber>
```

Then you're going to get errors.

(notice you have TxnDate and RefNumber *after* the AppliedToTxnAdd tag, when the spec defines it as coming *before* the AppliedToTxnAdd tag)

What it's trying to tell you here:

> The content of element type "ReceivePaymentAdd" must match
>   "(CustomerRef,ARAccountRef?,TxnDate?,RefNumber?,TotalAmount?,PaymentMethodRef?,Memo?,DepositToAccountRef?,CreditCardTxnInfo?,(IsAutoApply|AppliedToTxnAdd+)

Is that it's expecting tags in that order, and you sent them in a different order than it expected.

If you fix the order of the tags, it will work.

We have some [example qbXML requests](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests) on our [QuickBooks integration wiki guide](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks) if that helps.